# What is leaked about devices connected to iOS personal hotspot?

Tags: ios, hotspot

This is the scenario:

1) I set up a personal hotspot using my iPhone 4S running iOS 5 (we call this device A)

2) I connect a mobile device (e.g. a smartphone) using WiFi to have it use the hotspot for internet (we call this device B)

Is it then possible for outsiders to sniff information about device B, e.g. the IMEI/MAC address, if internet traffic over the hotspot is monitored?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but why do "*we call this device A*" if we never mention it again?

Comment: To make sure it is clear that I'm interested in what can be gathered about the device not making the internet connection, i.e. the one "behind" device A. There - I addressed it! :) Any input to the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason it must run iOS 5? Are you concerned about specific vulnerabilities in this version of iOS?